# Glue Crawler does not recognize Timestamps

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have JSON files in an S3 Bucket that may change their schema from time to time. To be able to analyze the data I want to run a glue crawler periodically on them, the analysis in Athena works in general.

Problem: My timestamp string is not recognized as timestamp

The timestamps currently have the following format `2020-04-06T10:37:38+00:00`, but I have also tried others, e.g. `2020-04-06 10:37:38` - I have control over this and can adjust the format.

The suggestion to set the serde parameters might not work for my application, I want to have the scheme completely recognized and not have to define each field individually. ([AWS Glue: Crawler does not recognize Timestamp columns in CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177686/aws-glue-crawler-does-not-recognize-timestamp-columns-in-csv-format))
Manual adjustments in the table are generally not wanted, I would like to deploy Glue automatically within a CloudFormation stack.

Do you have an idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. The way we got around the problem when reading text/json files is we had an extra step in between to cast and set proper data types. The crawler data types are a bit iffy sometimes and is based on the data sample available at that point in time

Comment: thanks. do you have any documentation how my timestamp needs to be formatted to be regognized as a timestamp type in a Glue Table? I tried several formats, no luck so far

Comment: Should have been more clear. U should probably use parquet as the intermediate file type so that the schema of the parquet file is used in the glue table definition. With regards to your question as to what time stamp format glue can detect as a time stamp type .... there doesn’t seem to be any specific documentation anywhere about that as far as I know. However it might be worth trying out the format mentioned in pyspark since I believe that’s what’s used in the backend

Comment: This is extract from spark docos

timestampFormat – sets the string that indicates a timestamp format. Custom date formats follow the formats at java.text.SimpleDateFormat. This applies to timestamp type. If None is set, it uses the default value, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX.

Comment: It may not be spark that it uses. But it’s worth a try if you’ve got the time

Comment: Thank you again!

I tried all of these formats with no luck:

2020-04-07T11:04:01.1586251321, 
2020-04-07 11:04:01, 
2020-04-07 11:04:01.1586251321, 
2020-04-07 11:04:01.1586251321+1, 
2020-04-07 11:04:01.1586251321+00:00, 
2020-04-07T11:04:01.1586251321+1, 
2020-04-07T11:04:01.1586251321+00:00, 
2020-04-07 11:04:01+1, 
2020-04-07T11:04:01+1, 
2020-04-07T11:04:01+01, 
2020-04-07 11:04:01+01

Any ideas?